# Print a variable in Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

iam beginner to jquery and javascript..please help me out.. I want to get the value of "x"  variable to be stored in HTML div's...

```
<script>
var x='';
$('#calendar').datepicker({
//altField: '#datepicker_send',
    inline: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      x = dateText;          
      //alert(x);
    }
});

<div class="evnt-p">No Events on : <script>document.write (x); </script> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to update the date when the datepicker value is changed so

```
<div class="evnt-p">No Events on : <span id="event-date"></span></div>
```

then

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
    //altField: '#datepicker_send',
    inline: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
        $('#event-date').text(dateText)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var x='';
$('#calendar').datepicker({

//altField: '#datepicker_send',

    inline: true,

    firstDay: 1,

    showOtherMonths: true,

    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],

     onSelect: function(dateText){
      x=dateText;          
      $('.evnt-p span').text(x);
          }
});

<div class="evnt-p">No Events on : <span></span> </div>
```

Working code